# DIV with SVG background won't completely cover parent

Tags: html, css, svg

So, check out the following code which has a parent div with banner inside it, and a child div which is mean to be an SVG "overlay" background inside it.  You can see that the overlay doesn't completely cover the parent, there is a small gap on the left and right side.

```css
.HeroImage {
     position: relative;
     width: 934px;
}
.HeroImage-Arc {
     position: absolute;
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     background: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 1440.5 82'%3E%3Cg%3E%3Cg%3E%3Cpath d='M1440.5,0q-360,82-720,82T.5,0L0,81.5H1440Z' style='fill:%23fff'/%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/svg%3E") center bottom no-repeat;
     top: 0;
}
```

```html
<section class="HeroImage">
  <img src="https://cdn.esigns.com/pub-data/prod/imagebox/9/887/Free-Product-Samples_Imagebox_Landing-Page-R.png">
  <div class="HeroImage-Arc"></div>
</section>
```

However, the second code sample below replaces the SVG with a PNG and it works fine.

```css
.HeroImage {
     position: relative;
     width: 934px;
}
.HeroImage-Arc {
     position: absolute;
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     background: url('data:image/png;base64,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') center bottom no-repeat;
     top: 0;
}
```

```html
<section class="HeroImage">
  <img src="https://cdn.esigns.com/pub-data/prod/imagebox/9/887/Free-Product-Samples_Imagebox_Landing-Page-R.png">
  <div class="HeroImage-Arc"></div>
</section>
```

The obvious solution is, use the PNG version.  However, this is a mostly academic question - I want to figure out why the SVG version isn't working - but it's also practical because the SVG version of a given image can often be much smaller, as is the case here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is incompatible aspect ratios.

Your SVG has an aspect ratio (from the viewBox) of:

```
1440.5/82 ~= 17.5671
```

when it tries to scale that down to the width of your `div` (934px) it gets a calculated size of:

```
width:  934
height: 934 / (1440.5 / 82) ~= 53.1677 px
```

It will be rounding that down to 53, and rendering the SVG into an intermediate bitmap of: 934px x 53px

But the SVG viewBox comes into play again because it wants to keep the aspect ratio correct when it renders the SVG.  So since the rendered height is less than 53.167px, the width will be as well.  It will end up at approx (934 * (53/53.1677)) ~= 931px.

You can mitigate these problems somewhat by:

1. Using viewBox and path coordinates that are rounded to whole units
2. Specify a `background-size` that won't cause the width to shrink to 931.  Eg. `934px 54px`.

```css
.HeroImage {
     position: relative;
     width: 934px;
}
.HeroImage-Arc {
     position: absolute;
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     background: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 1440 82'%3E%3Cg%3E%3Cg%3E%3Cpath d='M1440,0q-360,82-720,82T0,0L0,82H1440Z' style='fill:%23fff'/%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/svg%3E") center bottom no-repeat;
     top: 0;
     background-size: 934px 54px;
}
```

```html
<section class="HeroImage">
  <img src="https://cdn.esigns.com/pub-data/prod/imagebox/9/887/Free-Product-Samples_Imagebox_Landing-Page-R.png">
  <div class="HeroImage-Arc"></div>
</section>
```

This seems to work perfectly on Firefox, but there is still a sliver on the right in Chrome.  Probably due to some sort of rounding error.

The ultimate and simplest fix for that is to just have your path draw a couple of pixels outside the `viewBox`, so that the path is always drawn at least as far as the outside bounds.

For example, let's just make the path go from -2 to 1442, instead of 0 to 1440.

```css
.HeroImage {
     position: relative;
     width: 934px;
}
.HeroImage-Arc {
     position: absolute;
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     background: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 1440 82'%3E%3Cg%3E%3Cg%3E%3Cpath d='M1442,0q-360,82-720,82T-2,0L0,82H1442Z' style='fill:%23fff'/%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/svg%3E") center bottom no-repeat;
     top: 0;
     background-size: 934px 54px;
}
```

```html
<section class="HeroImage">
  <img src="https://cdn.esigns.com/pub-data/prod/imagebox/9/887/Free-Product-Samples_Imagebox_Landing-Page-R.png">
  <div class="HeroImage-Arc"></div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thank you for this excellent and informative answer.  I learned something new.

Answer (score 1):

You might use `svg` itself instead of `div.HeroImage-Arc`:

```css
.HeroImage {
     position: relative;
     width: 934px;
}
svg {
     position: absolute;
     width: 100%;
     bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<section class="HeroImage">
  <img src="https://cdn.esigns.com/pub-data/prod/imagebox/9/887/Free-Product-Samples_Imagebox_Landing-Page-R.png">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 1440.5 82"><path fill="#fff" d="M1440.5 0q-360 82-720 82T0 0L0 81.5h1440.5z"/></svg>
</section>
```