# one pixel vertical line (or vertical lines on sides) around SVG for some screen sizes

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm using SVG for these swirly divider graphics between sections. For some reason in some screen sizes it shows up a small 1px vertical line just under the SVG (it comes from the background), or vertical lines on sides. I don't know how to fix it. The color comes from the section background here.

```css
#booster2 {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #0067d0, #0f9bff);
  position: relative;
}

  .booster2-bg::before {
    background: url("https://covershark.com/temp/booster2-divider-top.svg") center top no-repeat;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
    height: 350px;
    z-index: 0;
  }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>

<BR><BR><BR>
<section id="booster2">
  <div class="booster2-bg">
    <div class="container">
      test<BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>





</body>
</html>
```

Here are the image examples for 2 screen sizes:

[vertical lines on sides for 898px screen size width](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1DIqX.png)

[horizontal 1px line at the top for the 899px screen size width](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OrnE9.png)

Comment: Most likely a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51542583/div-with-svg-background-wont-completely-cover-parent/51564297

Answer (score 0):

Try to add an explicit [`background-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size):

```css
.booster2-bg::before {
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    padding-top: 13.633%; /* instead of fixed `height` to maintain aspect ratio */
}
```

I would also get rid of `position: absolute`, so that the block could automatically adjust its height without overlapping adjacent elements vertically. Just use `display: block` instead.